# Restricting Amazon S3 access only on VPN connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I have hosted a web application on an Amazon S3 bucket and we are trying to restrict the access to the application within our VPN. So we have added the below policy to restrict the access only when we are connected to VPN. We are using Terraform software tool and Jenkins for building and deploying the application into Amazon S3 buckets.

For the first time when we deploy the application, it gets deployed successfully and also able to restrict only to VPN connected users. But now the problem I am facing is when I try to deploy the application for the second time, deployment is failing due to access restriction(Forbidden access error) and the reason for this is, our jenkins server is not on VPN and terraform refresh is failing with 403 error. The code I have used is as below.

```
"Sid": "VPNAccessIP",
  "Action": "s3:GetObject",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3::: demo-dev",
    "arn:aws:s3::: demo-dev/*"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "NotIpAddress": {
      "aws:SourceIp": [
        "130.110.0.0/22"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Principal": "*"
```

Is there any other approach to achieve the access restriction only for VPN connection and also it should allow deploying the application from Jenkins?

Comment: Why can't you add the Jenkins server IP along with VPN IP in policy ?

Comment: There are a few different ways to go here, but this question is probably more of a [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) question than a Stack Overflow one, because it's about AWS services rather than programming. With that said, one possible answer would be to use a [VPC Service Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html) so your Jenkins server (running in a VPC, presumably) can access the S3 bucket from a private address rather than a public one. This acts as a sort of bridge between your VPC network and the S3 service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use VPC Endpoint for S3, type Gateway.
Using VPC Endpoint with policy below will only allow access from your on-premise IP range and from VPCE.

VPC Endpoint type gateway is not charged, so it is a good way to use S3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Access-from-specific-VPCE-or-IP-only",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::demo-dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::demo-dev/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-abcde12345"
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "130.110.0.0/22"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```